# How to get more speed from "almost" 1GB-cable?

Tags: networking

**SITUATION**

In my house (built 2007) I have several Cat7 cables (S/FTP PiMF) from Room A,B,C, ... to Room X. On all (tested) cables I get a 1GB connection (cheap home type 1GB switches), only on ONE I only get 100 MBit (most likely I folded the cable a bit to much while placing it).

I wonder if there is a switch (or other device) that could get a 1GB connect on a "poor quality" cable? With powerlan going up to 500MBit, there should be a solution >100MBit if there a 4 TP lines, shouldn't it?

**I tried:**

PC --- switch --- wall-plug --- underfloor cable --- patchpanel --- switch

PC connects to switch with 1GB. Switch connects to second switch with 100MBit (other cables in same config work 1GB). Patchcable is Cat6. Wall-plug is Cat6, fully shielded (same as all others in the house).

PC --- wall-plug --- underfloor cable --- patchpanel --- switch

Still 100MBit. Tried two switches: EDITMAX ES-5500G and Longshine LCS-7108A, same results. I also reconnected the cable to the patchpanel, same result.

Comment: Just replace the ends on the cable. 99% probability the problem is the ends. (What wiring pattern did you use?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I used 586B. I have already cut the cable from the patchpanel and connected a modular Cat6 module (Dätwyler). I hesite to try the same on the wall-plug side (, because the cable that comes out of the wall is only 8-9 cm and it's VERY uncomfortable to try to reconnect it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Great (almost)! Now I have Dätwyler KS-TS6 on both ends and it works! Just need to get it back into the wall :(